Update of Jupyter extension in VSCodium fails
The Jupyter extension for VS Code wants to update but fails to do so. I am not sure which version of the extension I had installed before I uninstalled it and then tried to reinstall (read below). I don't have this issue with any other extension, which means I can install other extensions from the GUI within VSCodium without issues. I am using VSCodium (version 1.88.1, snap) on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.
Jupyter Extension wants to update
When I click the "Update to v..." button, I get the following error:
[error] Invalid comment length. Expected: 63. Found: 0. Are there extra bytes at the end of the file? Or is the end of central dir signature `PK☺☻` in the comment?: Extract: Invalid comment length. Expected: 63. Found: 0. Are there extra bytes at the end of the file? Or is the end of central dir signature `PK☺☻` in the comment?
    at z.extractUserExtension (/snap/codium/388/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:104:137968)
    at async ie.extractExtension (/snap/codium/388/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:104:146548)
    at async ie.downloadAndInstallExtension (/snap/codium/388/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:104:149661)
    at async ie.install (/snap/codium/388/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:104:148742)
    at async ie.doRun (/snap/codium/388/usr/share/codium/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:104:145848)

I tried uninstalling the extension and reinstalling.

from the VSCodium GUI (whereas the extension version would be 2024.5.0)
from terminal by downloading the .vsix file from the marketplace first and then running codium --install-extension ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.5.0.vsix and after failing i tried codium --install-extension ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.3.1.vsix

Both methods returned the same error message. Between the two non-installing versions the only thing changing in the error message is the number after Expected:; for one version it's 63 and for the other one it's 65. I then tried to download the 2023.9.100 version and install this one and it worked.
Comparing the .vsix files, I noticed that the 2023.9.100 version was an archive while the two newer versions were just text files.
2023.9.100 vsix-file is an archive
2024.5.0 and 2024.3.1 vsix-files are text files with weird symbols

Seems that the extension got a text header.
What i did to install it:

With an editor removed the first 3 lines from the file (the 'PK' must be the first 2 bytes).

Created an empty directory an unzipped it into this new dir.

Changed to this directory and created a zip file:
zip ~/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2024.3.1.vsix -r .

Installed this vsix file with success...


Edit #1: the 2024.5.0 is for 1.89.0 and up, so you need to fix the version 2024.3.1
Edit #2: Check this issue (scroll down the bottom): https://github.com/open-vsx/publish-extensions/issues/740

Thanks for your help! Now that they fixed it, I was able to just install 2024.3.1 directly from the store GUI.
